# Reducing a normalized table to one value

Tags: sql

I'm sure this has been asked but I'm not quite sure how to properly search for this question, my apologies.

I have two tables, Foo and Bar.  For has one row per Food, bar has many rows per food matching descriptors.

### Foo

name         id
Apple 1
Orange 2

### Bar

id description
1  Tasty
1  Ripe
2 Sweet

etc (sorry for the somewhat contrived example).

I'm trying to return a query where if, for each row in Foo, Bar contains a descriptor in ('Tasty', 'Juicy') return true
ex:

### Output

Apple True
Orange False

I had been solving this somewhat trivially with a case when I only had one item to match

select 
Foo.name, 
case bar.description 
when 'Tasty' then True 
else 'False' 
end 
from Foo 
left join Bar on foo.id = bar.id 
where bar.description = 'Tasty'

But with multiple items, I keep ending up with extra rows:

### Output

Apple True 
Apple False

etc etc

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to think about this problem or what I should be doing?  Thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS? The most efficient way will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a subquery

```
select foo.name
from foo
where foo.id in (
   select bar.id
   from bar
   where bar.description in ('Tasty', 'Juicy')
)
```

As Martin pointed out, the above query doesn't quite provide what the OP wants. Below is a fixed version.

```
select 
     foo.name, 
     case 
         when r.id is null then 'True' 
         else 'False' 
     end as IsTastyOrJucy
from foo 
   left join (
       select foo.name
       from foo
       where foo.id in (
          select bar.id
          from bar
          where bar.description in ('Tasty', 'Juicy')
       )
    ) as R
```

Comment: The OP wants all rows from foo with a true or false. Not just the true ones. This won't return "Orange"

Comment: I would up-vote you, but I'm out of votes at the moment. That said, I wanted to point out that you generally want to use `exists` rather than `in` for these kinds of queries. The intent is clearer, and `exists` handles `null` values in a more robust way.

Comment: @WCWedin: Generally I use `exists`, but I've found those new to SQL find `in` easier to get to grips with when starting out; although your point about the handling of `null` values is well made.

Comment: `NULL` s don't make any difference here. It would for `NOT IN`

Comment: @Martin: That's true. Is it ever dangerous to use `exists`, though? I would argue that `in` should be reserved for situations where `exists` doesn't apply – e.g., when you are matching a column against a given set (`in ('Tasty', 'Juicy')`).

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something like the following, depending on your DBMS:

```
SELECT
        id, name,
        CAST(CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM bar WHERE
                    bar.id = foo.id
                    AND bar.description IN ('Tasty', 'Juicy')
                ) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS BIT) AS HasBar
    FROM
        foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select id, name
from foo
where exists (
    select 1 from bar where bar.id = foo.id 
    and bar.Description in ('tasty', 'ripe')
)
```

Comment: The OP wants all rows from foo with a true or false. Not just the true ones.

Comment: Please note that this doesn't return the wanted output. A `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE` version in the select body would be more appropriate maybe.

Comment: +1 This is almost right, but you need to move the `exists` clause into the `select` clause, inside a case statement. Also, you can `select null` inside an `exists` clause with the same results.

Comment: @WCWedin: Actually you can select anything, the query will be optimized anyways. Try `SELECT 1/0`

Comment: Got it, I wasn't thinking in subqueries, thank you for the reply. (it won't let me accept for a few more minutes, but I will when it allows me).

Comment: Just use `*`. Using a Constant is not an optimisation at all.

Comment: @Alex Bagnolini, Martin: It was more of a stylistic point than an optimization. Arbitrary constants could be confusing to someone maintaining the query, and `select *` is a dangerous habit in production code. I prefer `select null` because it draws attention to itself for the uninitiated; it entices curiosity and forces someone reading the query to focus on the fact that the `select` clause is part of an `exists` clause.

Comment: @Martin - my bad, didn't read that properly.   As for the constant in the exists, I prefer it for readability, it's not an optimisation...

Comment: Paddy - Sorry I think I was a bit unnecessarily grumpy yesterday! @WCWedin Regarding using `NULL` the other place where I see constants used except `*` is in `SELECT COUNT(1)...` rather than `SELECT COUNT(*)` Using Null wouldn't work here.  `SELECT COUNT(NULL)` would of course conceptually always return 0 (though actually SQL Server gives the error "Operand data type void type is invalid for count operator." if you try). What idiom do you use for that?

Comment: @Martin: Good question! If the database uses surrogate keys (or any non-nullable primary key), I would count those. Otherwise, I think I would prefer COUNT(1), but I haven't had to deal with that before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
SELECT  F.Name, 
            CASE WHEN B.Description IN ('Tasty', 'Juicy') 
                  THEN 'True' 
                  ELSE 'False' 
            END AS IsTastyOrJuicy
FROM Foo AS F
LEFT JOIN Bar AS B ON B.ID = F.ID
GROUP BY F.Name, B.Description
```

[Proof with your sample data pasted over at PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/wSa78kxh).

Comment: Unfortunately this query produces bad output if an apple is both 'Jucy' and 'Ripe' :-(